# Pass stream hint to existing texture?

Tags: opengl, textures

I have a texture that was created by another part of my code (with QT5's bindTexture, but this isn't relevant).

How can I set an OpenGL hint that this texture will be frequently updated?

```
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    //Tell opengl that I plan on streaming this texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mechanism to indicating that a texture will be updated repeatedly; that is only related to buffers (e.g., VBOs, etc.) through the *usage* parameter.  However, there are two possibilities:

1. Attache your texture as a framebuffer object and update it that way.  That's probably the most efficient method to do what you're asking.  The memory associated with the texture remains resident on the GPU, and you can update it at rendering speeds.
2. Try using a *pixel buffer object* (commonly called a PBO, and has an OpenGL buffer type of `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER`) as the buffer that Qt writes its generated texture into, and mark that buffer as `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW`.  You'll still need to call `glTexImage*D()` with the buffer offset of the PBO (i.e., probably zero) for each update, but that approach may afford some efficiency over just blasting texels to the pipe directly through `glTexImage*D()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such hint. OpenGL defines functionality, not performance. Just upload to it whenever you need to.